# PL/SQL baser website development

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I want to develop a website for a book library. The website has to have following features:

1. There would be a member login system.
2. Its members can issue books(not more than two at a time).
3. When they're issuing a book, the button correspondent to it will be discoloured automatically.
4. The issued books' names will be queued and an administrator can see it.
5. When they're returning the books, the administrator can set its availability on.

I hope, you can guess what I need to do. That's the least. There'd be form for member joining, a corner for requesting a new book etc etc. Can all these things be processed by pl/sql ?

I don't have knowledge on php. I've worked with oracle 10 xe, pl/sql. I can edit an html/css template.
We're from a volunteering library, so we don't have money. All I need to do myself, even after learning it (that's one kind of beauty, I've done simillar thing before).
Would you kindly suggest me how to do it so that I need to learn comparatively less things?

Answer (score 3):

If you're already familiar with PL/SQL, the easiest option is probably to use [Oracle Application Express (APEX)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html) to build the site.  If you are using the 10.2 version of Oracle XE rather than the 11.2 version, you can read the [HTML DB 2 Day Developer Guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_toc?pathname=appdev.102/b14377/toc.htm&remark=portal%20%28Application%20development%29) (HTML DB is the old name for the product that became APEX).  Or, if you're willing to upgrade to the 11.2 version of Oracle XE, the [APEX 2 Day Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11946/toc.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I host that site for free? Our local hosting providers don't support apex built website hosting.

Comment: @Pro_nerd - If you have a hosting provider that will let you host a 10g database, you should be able to build the site using APEX since that's part of the database.  You can host the site entirely in the database or you can put an Apache web server in front of the database.  Of course, unless they're donating the hosting, I doubt that there are any hosting providers that would let you run any sort of web site on any platform for free.

Comment: None of our local service providers are offering 10 g database hosting. Another question, can about 100 users log into that system?Thanksfor your continuous support. Our Library will remember you!

Comment: @Pro_nerd - An APEX application can have as many users logged in as the database and code can support.  If you're talking about an XE database, the limits on RAM and CPU (1 GB of RAM and 1 CPU) could make supporting 100 simultaneous users a bit problematic if they're actually all doing something at the same time.  If, however, they are mostly idle (as most users are), it would probably be fine.  But if you need to host the site and none of the hosting providers offer an Oracle database, I guess I'm confused as to why you tagged the question for Oracle.

Comment: I didn't know before that our local providers don't support oracle database.

Comment: @Pro_nerd - It's probably helpful, then, to edit your question to incorporate this new information.  If using Oracle is not an option, remove the `Oracle10g` and `plsql` tags (and probably the `sql` tags), describe what technologies you can use, and retag appropriately.  I'll delete my answer once that's done in case you want to copy something from the comments.